# stack exchange global inbox

Tags: support, stack-exchange, global-inbox

I asked a question on Ask Ubuntu.  I received an email from someone responding to my question.  He responded with a question that the email to me says is in my "Stack Exchange Global Inbox".  I don't know what that is, nor how to access it.  When I click on the inbox icon at the top of the screen, the message sent to me isn't in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notification was removed from your inbox because the answer (which should have been posted as a comment) got deleted.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Just curious:  Who would have deleted it from my inbox?  I didn't.  (Not complaining, just trying to understand how this works.  I agree with the idea that the person should have responded to my question in the forum instead of via a private message.)

Comment: The system automatically removes it when the post is deleted, because it would otherwise just be linking you to nothing.